# Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I noticed that my computer timezone was set to `(UTC-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada)`, so I changed it to `(UTC+08:00) Kuala Lumpur, Singapore`.
And then when I open Azure storage explorer, it shows up the error below.

[image]

I tried uninstalling Azure Storage Explorer, but the error still exist.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure your computer time in UTC is correct?  By changing the time zones, did you by chance also change the time on the machine?

Comment: I'm sure now that my timezone is correct (+08:00). I just changed my computer timezone, and also the time.

Comment: I would triple verify that your time is correct regardless of time zone (ie: on UTC basis)... Whenever you're more than 5-8 minutes off, you'll have troubles connecting to Azure API's and various other WCF-based resources

Comment: if I would set the timezone to -08:00, it will work now. But my UTC timezone should be set to +08:00. What should I do?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I got the solution above. :D

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution here.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738995(WS.10).aspx

Error gone! :D

To restore Windows Time service on local computer to default settings

Open a Command Prompt.
Type the following command and then press ENTER:

```
net stop w32time
```

Type the following command and then press ENTER:

```
w32tm /unregister
```

Type the following command and then press ENTER:

```
w32tm /register
```

Type the following command and then press ENTER:

```
net start w32time
```