# Connecting to Azure Blob Storage in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, azure

I am trying to connect to my Azure Storage Account in SSMS as such (using my real storage account name and using Access Key 1 which I copy and pasted from the Azure Portal):

[image]

But I am getting back a 403 Forbidden:

> Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of
>   Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.StorageClient)

Am I missing a configuration option on the Azure Portal?

Comment: I'm able to connect to my Azure Storage account using SSMS. I would recommend checking the account name/key. As a side note, do take a look at Server Explorer in Visual Studio. It is much better alternative for managing Azure Storage than SSMS.

Comment: I will look at Server Explorer instead, I just use SSMS for my other SQL databses and figured it would be nice to have them all in one place. Its weird because the key and name are totally correct but it seems to be a permissions header issue. Thanks for the response

Comment: I thought it might be a version issue at first, but I tried connecting from SSMS 2012, 2014, 2016 preview, all succeed. Really weird. Maybe it's related to the time zone setting, changing time zone settings could lead to this issue, check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21856363/server-failed-to-authenticate-the-request-make-sure-the-value-of-authorization

Comment: +1 @forester123. Apart from incorrect account name/key combination, other reason for this error when the clock on your machine is out of sync by +/- 15 minutes as compared to the clock on storage service. Please check for that as well.

Comment: How can I check the clock on the storage service? The location is East US which is where I am located as well.

Comment: Are you using a Standard Storage account or Premium Storage? Also, are you able to access the same account from the same machine using a different Azure Storage Explorer?

Comment: Standard Storage account from my Free Trial. This is my only storage account on my Azure subscription. I have not tried Azure Storage Explorer but am looking at it now and will give it a shot.

Comment: Just by downloading and logging in to my Azure Account in Azure Storage Explorer I can see my blob succesfully in the directory without even me having to enter the name and access key. While I still have the same reproducable problem using SSMB 2016 RC.

Comment: Were you able to figure out this issue?